# TestNG method Sequence from TestNG.xml

Tags: java, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have Two class and I put this on TestNG.xml but it does not run sequentially My classes are  like that

```
    public class TestBase {

    @Parameters({"paraTest"})

@Test(groups = "gp1",singleThreaded = true)
public void runMethodGP1(String a) throws InterruptedException {
        //Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("Invoked testString " + a);
    System.out.println("runMethodGP1()");
}

@Test(groups = "gp2",singleThreaded = true)
public void runMethodGP2() {
    System.out.println("runMethodGP2()");
}

@Test(groups = "gp3",singleThreaded = true)
public void runMethodGP3() {
    System.out.println("runMethodGP3()");
}

@Test(groups = "gp1",singleThreaded = true)
public void runMethod2GP1() {
    System.out.println("runMethod2GP1()");
}

@Test(groups = "gp2",singleThreaded = true)
public void runMethod2GP2() {
    System.out.println("runMethod2GP2()");
}


public class TestNGAnotationClass1 {

@Test(groups = "gp1")
public void runMethod3GP1CL1() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println("runMethod3GP1CL1()");
}

@Test(groups = "gp3")
public void runMethod2GP3CL1() {
    System.out.println("runMethod2GP3CL1()");
}
}
```

My TestNG.xml is like that

```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
  <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
  <suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" order-by-instances="true" preserve-order="true">

<test name="TestNGAnotationClass2" time-out="1" preserve-order="true" annotations="JDK">
    <parameter name="paraTest" value="Test">
    </parameter>
    <classes>
        <class name="excelfilereadapachepoi.TestBase">
        </class>
        <class name="excelfilereadapachepoi.TestNGAnotationClass1">
        </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Output:

runMethod2GP1()
runMethod2GP2()
Invoked testString Test
runMethodGP1()
runMethodGP2()
runMethodGP3()
runMethod2GP3CL1()

But it should be like that

Invoked testString Test
runMethodGP1()
runMethodGP2()
runMethod2GP1()
runMethod2GP2()
runMethodGP3()
runMethod2GP3CL1()

Can any body tell me where I am wrong.

I am using TestNG 6.8.1

Comment: TestNG makes no guarantee as to the order of tests -- rightfully so. If you want tests to run in a certain order, use `dependsOn{Methods,Groups}` and/or `priority`

Comment: @ fge thanks for your comments.    
 
I using priority in @Test to overcome this condition but I want to know can I use only TestNG.xml settings to overcome this condition or I need also configure @ Test(Priority="some Integer value") because in TestNG.xml file have already preserve-order="true" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly in that you want to run tests in a specified order, TestNG IMethodInterceptor can be used. Take a look at http://beust.com/weblog2/archives/000479.html on how to leverage them.

OR

Use dependsOnMethods and/or dependsOnGroups:

Comment: I using priority in @Test to overcome this condition but I want to know can I use only TestNG.xml settings to overcome this condition or I need also configure @ Test(Priority="some Integer value") because in TestNG.xml file have already preserve-order="true" attribute.